# How to serve a pdf file from GCS in GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm using Google App Engine in Python to handle a small webapp.

I have some files stored in my GCS that I want to serve only if the user is logged in.

I though it was really easy, but for sure I'm missing a step since my code:

```
import cloudstorage as gcs

class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write(self, *a, **kw):
        self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)

class testHandler (Handler):
    def get (self):
        bucket = '/my_bucket'
        filename = '/pdf/somedoc.pdf'
        user = users.get_current_user()
        if user:
            pdf = gcs.open(bucket+filename)
            self.write(pdf)
```

only gives:

```
<cloudstorage.storage_api.ReadBuffer object at 0xfbb931d0>
```

and what I need is the file itself.

Anyone can tell me which is the step I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

After some thinking, shower and coffee, I realized I had two problems.

First I was writing the address of the file, not the file.

So the correct call would be:

```
self.write(pdf.read())
```

Also, I had to change the 'Content-Type' header to 'application/pdf', to allow the browser to serve the file and not a text file.

Anyhow, the result was:

```
class pHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write(self, *a, **kw):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type']='application/pdf'
        self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)

class testHandler (pHandler):
    def get (self):
        bucket = '/my_bucket'
        filename = '/pdf/somedoc.pdf'
        user = users.get_current_user()
        if user:
            pdf = gcs.open(bucket+filename)
            self.write(pdf.read())
```

Answer (score 1):

Even the PO has answered his question, just want to add a few thoughts.

PO's code is to write the content of pdf file into http response.

```
self.write(pdf.read())
```

According to [GAE quota limitation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/requests#Python_Quotas_and_limits), if the response size is larger than 32MB, it will fail.

Also, it would be good to set the [urlfetch_timeout](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/retryparams_class) value, as default value of 5 seconds may not be enough in some circumstance, and would result in [DeadlineExceededError](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deadlineexceedederrors).

I would recommend to try, when a request is received, use Google Cloud Storage API ( Not the GAE one ) to [copy](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/storage/v1/python/latest/storage_v1.objects.html#copy) the file to a temporary location. Also Make sure to set the acl of the new object as publicly readable, then serve the public url of the new object.

Also, send a request to a taskqueue, set [eta](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/tasks#eta_arg) of the task to a timeout value of your choice. Once the task is executed, remove the file from the temporary location, so that it could no longer be accessed.

UPDATE:

Use [Service Account Auth](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#service_accounts), Generate a new JSON key, get the private key.

Set the scope to FULL_CONTROL as we need to change acl settings.

I havn't test the code yet as I am at work. But will do when i have time.

```
import httplib2
from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.errors import HttpError
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials


# Need to modify ACL, therefore need full control access
GCS_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control'


def get_gcs_client( project_id, 
                    service_account=None,
                    private_key=None):

    credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(service_account, private_key, scope=GCS_SCOPE)

    http = httplib2.Http()
    http = credentials.authorize(http)
    service = build('storage', 'v2', http=http)

    return service
```

Comment: Your idea sounds good, but I've been trying the whole afternoon to find where and how I can import GCS API to my app without any luck.
Can you give me a starting point? Im quite lost

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be better off using the BlobStore API on GCS to serve this kind of files. Based on [Using the Blobstore API with Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Using_the_Blobstore_API_with_Google_Cloud_Storage), I've come up with this approach:

```
import cloudstorage as gcs
import webapp2

from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers

GCS_PREFIX = '/gs'
BUCKET = '/my_bucket'
FILE = '/pdf/somedoc.pdf'
BLOBSTORE_FILENAME = GCS_PREFIX + BUCKET + FILE

class GCSWebAppHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        blob_key = blobstore.create_gs_key(BLOBSTORE_FILENAME)
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'
        self.response.write(blobstore.fetch_data(blob_key, 0, blobstore.MAX_BLOB_FETCH_SIZE - 1))

class GCSBlobDlHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
    def get(self):
        blob_key = blobstore.create_gs_key(BLOBSTORE_FILENAME)
        self.send_blob(blob_key)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/webapphandler', GCSWebAppHandler),
    ('/blobdlhandler', GCSServingHandler)],
    debug=True)
```

As you can see, there are two example handlers you can use here, `webapphandler` and `blobdlhandler`. It's probably better to use the latter, since the former is limited by `MAX_BLOB_FETCH_SIZE` in `fetch_data()` which is 1MB, but if your served files are smaller than this size, it's ok.